# Proc Neural Error in SAS. Catalog xxx.yyy Does Not Exist

Tags: sas, neural-network

So I am running proc neural in SAS enterprise miner and I keep getting the error message below. I have referenced and used the exact same dataset in other procedures within the same program. I have created the library `data1` that consists of the `blahblah` data. Anyone have any idea why this will not work? I am beyond baffled by this. Just to clarify, `libname data1 'filepath';` was used to create my library and `filepath` does contain the `blahblah.sas7bdat` file.

```
proc neural data=data1.blahblah dmdbcat=data1.blahblah random=12345;
```

> NOTE: Data file `DATA1.blahblah.DATA is in a format that is native to another host, or the file encoding does not match the session encoding. Cross Environment Data Access will be used, which might require additional CPU resources and reduce performance.
>   NOTE: PROCEDURE NEURAL used (Total process time):
>         real time           0.01 seconds
>         cpu time            0.01 seconds
>
> ERROR: Catalog DATA1.blahblah does not exist.
>   ERROR:  The DMDB catalog DATA1.blahblah was constructed from a data set with no valid observations.
>   NOTE: Closing the Neural Application.
>   NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
>   7257

```
architecture=MLP hidden 10/ id=middle act=log bias combine=add;
input blah blah blah blah blah blah /id=inputs;
prelim 5 preiter=10;quit;
target=bad/id=predict_layer combine=add bias act=log ;
outest=estimate;
outfit=fitness;
nloptions=noprint;
run;
```

Comment: Not sure about PROC NEURAL but the error message is saying that there were no observations in the input dataset and so the proc was unable to create the output catalog.  Look at the input dataset with some other proc (like PROC CONTENTS) to see if actually has any data.  Also make sure that you are not running with option OBS=0.  SAS will set that in response to errors.  You can try resetting it to OBS=MAX.

Comment: You mention that your `.sas7bdat` file is there, but is also there the `.sas7bcat` catalog? If so, you can try to visualize its contents with `PROC CONTENTS`, or `PROC DATASETS` with a `CONTENTS` statement.

Comment: SAS Desktop has, in Additional Languages, a UTF8-compliant version of the main application. From this application, you could try and access the contents (and eventually convert) those files... If they were indeed written with UTF8 encoding (which is plausible), you should be ok.

Comment: It ended up being something silly. I have to use a proc dmdb before I can run the proc neural.